# Why doesn't 'drush cc all' work?

Tags: 8, drush

I installed Drush, but most of the commands doesn't work, I guess. I tried `drush cc all` and got the following output:

> Command cache-clear needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command.
>   The drush command 'cc all' could not be executed.
>   A Drupal installation directory could not be found

`drush status` outputs the following:

> PHP configuration     :  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
>   Drush version         :  4.5
>   Drush configuration   :
>   Drush alias files     :

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to **rebuild** cache with Drupal 8, rather than clear it:

```
drush cr
```

Comment: Got the same . The drush command 'cr all' could not be found.

Comment: Sounds like you're not running inside a Drupal website. The above is sound though, there's no `drush cc` for Drupal 8

Comment: yes am running from /var/www-drupal , and its giving output for drush status

Comment: but status is not listing fully i guess : PHP configuration     :  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
 Drush version         :  4.5
 Drush configuration   :
 Drush alias files     :

Comment: Yep, same reason. You're not running it in the root of a Drupal website, or Drupal can't detect that fact (settings.php might be inaccessible to drush, for example)

Comment: when i run from /var/drupal/core i got the following : PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface' not found in /var/www-drupal/core/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 58
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Drupal' not found in /var/www-drupal/core/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 296

Comment: try " drush cr " instead of using drush cr all :)

Comment: "drush cr all" comes back with message of 'too many arguments'. "drush cr" seems to work. not sure why this is the Accepted and top voted answer. perhaps it was correct in Apr 2016 and has changed since?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Very likely, thanks for the comment I've updated to the current way :)

Comment: ah cool. glad making the comment was worthwhile - will upvote now too

Answer (score 5):

- Update Drush (at least Drush 8.0 is required for Drupal 8)
  See [How to install drush 8 properly?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/166879/how-to-install-drush-8-properly) or http://www.jpstacey.info/blog/2014-04-07/switching-between-drush-major-versions.
- Use `drush cr` instead of `drush cc all`

Answer (score 2):

You can even try:

- drupal 7 :drush cache-clear all
- drupal 8 : drush cache-rebuild

Refer two articles you can have some more idea on clearing and rebuilding cache:

1. http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/drupal-8-first-impressions-back-end-developer
2. https://www.drupal.org/documentation/clearing-rebuilding-cache

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using Drush 8.* for Drupal 8? I believe your version is just outdated. (And you need `drush cr` as Clive pointed out.)

Comment: I installed drush from this link : http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/ , seems like its old

Comment: I have used composer ([alternative install](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install-alternative/)) Note that that example downloads Drush 7, so you'll need to change that into an 8

Answer (score 0):

If your drush status does not say anything about the database then it is not connecting to the database and thinks your site is effectively dead.   This is very VERY common for new sites.  Possible fixes:

1. Make sure your in the same directory that the index.php file is in for drupal.

or if in multisite setup then.

2. Make sure you are in the $rootdir/sites/yoursitename/ subdirectory when you execute "drush st".

or

3. Make sure you supply the --uri="myawesomesite.local" to tell drush which settings.php file to try to find and use.
4. Make sure you can load your site in your browser first.

See sample screenshot[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me on ever single D7 installation and I solve it by changing the host setting for the DB in my settings.php file from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1[image]"