# Install issues via composer

Tags: drush, installation

I ran composer global require drush/drush:dev-master. I'm not sure how to  resolvirthis issue as it seems that the package isn't found anymore. Do I have to update somehow?

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for drush/drush dev-master -> satisfiable by drush/drush[dev-master].
    - drush/drush dev-master requires codegyre/robo ~1.0.0-beta1 -> satisfiable by codegyre/robo[1.0.0-beta1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a work around without using composer to do the install by doing the following:

1. make a drush directory in your home folder (~)
2. git clone https://github.com/drush-ops/drush.git
3. cd into that directory
4. ./drush --version (it should complain about composer install)
5. run **composer install**
6. ./drush --version **WORKING!**

I'm using ubuntu so initially I did **apt-get install drush**, but that version is 5. Then I did the following to download the latest into ~/drush

From there I went to my global run folder: /usr/bin and renamed the old drush to drush_old and then did a **ln -s ~/drush/drush drush** now its on the latest drush!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `codegyre/robo` project has moved to `consolidation/Robo`, so Drush needs to be updated.

See also: [drush/drush dev-master requires codegyre/robo ~1.0.0-beta1](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200539/drush-drush-dev-master-requires-codegyre-robo-1-0-0-beta1).

---

I've merged a PR into the Drush master branch that fixes the problems Drush was having with Robo. It is still complicated to install the master branch of Drush with Composer. This will get better after the stable release of Robo 1.0.0, or after I implement a fix for [this issue](https://github.com/consolidation-org/cgr/issues/2). Until then, I recommend against installing Drush master via `composer require`. Either install Drush 8.x, or, if you need the master branch, use `git clone` followed by `composer install`.

Comment: Just did a **composer global require codegyre/robo:~1.0.0-beta1** and now I get an issue with symfony: http://prnt.sc/c3nytf ---- I'm not sure how to go about resolving that now. I then went to your link and as you said just use stable drush 8 and now I'm getting this: http://prntscr.com/c3o8tc --- I dont understand why its so complicated to install drush. It installed fine a few months back and now I'm getting all these dependency problems. thanks Greg!

Comment: In your second screenshot, the problem is that you have not placed Drush in your $PATH. Note the difference between `composer require` (run from a composer-managed Drupal project) and `composer global require` (to install a global Drush). We do not recommend `composer global require` when installing Drush.  If you'd like a global Drush, please see and use https://github.com/consolidation-org/cgr

Comment: Tried installing your cgr... getting a "nothing to install or update" ---> http://prntscr.com/c3t3r3 .... I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or what am I missing to make this seem so difficult to install.

Comment: i just did a **sudo apt-get install drush** and its working, but its drush version 5. =(

Comment: nvm i got a work around by doing a git clone of your repo. I'm curious to why not suggest a git clone of your repo and then just run it off of that? it just seems so much easier than having to deal with dependencies when doing the install via composer directly.