# Installing Drush 8 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drush

I am having problems installing drush 8 in ubuntu 16.04. when i insert the following command in the terminal

```
composer global require drush/drush:dev-master
```

i get the following error
[image]

I have also tried the documentation from drush.org

```
php -r "readfile('https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.drush.org/drush.phar');" > drush
```

but i get the following error msg

> bash: drush: Is a directory

I am currently stuck.

Comment: To show error messages, please copy-paste the text. Don't use screenshots for text.

Comment: @kiamlaluno This question is originally not asking the same thing as the old post. It is the further question after solving the original question. So I think it should not be marked as duplicate.

Comment: @JimmyKo Actually, the first revision didn't even contain an explicit question, nor did it contain any useful details. It was edited after I closed it, but the edit invalidates the given answers, so it needs to be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

`drush/drush:dev-master` is not Drush 8, it is Drush 9.  To install Drush 8, try `composer global require drush/drush`, or better yet, use [cgr](https://github.com/consolidation-org/cgr).

For notes on installing Drush 9 via Composer, please see [drush dev-master requires codegyre-robo](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200539/drush-drush-dev-master-requires-codegyre-robo-1-0-0-beta1).

Comment: I am getting the following error "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages." when i ran this "composer global require drush/drush"

Comment: `composer global require` can fail if you install two global applications that conflict with each other. To resolve this problem, use cgr (https://github.com/consolidation-org/cgr).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `sudo`.

```
sudo composer global require drush/drush:dev-master
```

The composer is to install the drush at `/usr/local/share` which folder's owner is `root`. In Ubuntu, `sudo` is a must for granting the `root` privilege.

And, as what @greg_1_anderson said, `dev-master` is the branch for Drush 9, if you want Drush 8. Please use.

```
sudo composer global require drush/drush:8.x
```

Comment: I am getting the following error "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages" when i run this sudo composer global require drush/drush:8.x

Comment: I am getting the same error message as the one i posted as a problem when i ran this command "sudo composer global require drush/drush:dev-master"

Comment: @IanNato It should be considered as new question because the original thing you are asking should be solved by using `sudo`. The new error message is indicating the other problem. You should use `cgr` as stated as @greg_1_anderson to fix the new error.

Comment: You should not run composer with sudo because plugins have full access to the user account that runs composer and this is a security issue https://getcomposer.org/root

Comment: Installation passed, but when I try "drush --version" I get "-bash: /usr/bin/drush: No such file or directory"

Comment: @MilanG You need to add the composer path (i.e. export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH) to ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc.